# Find most frequant values with Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following data set:

```
dump DATA_INPUT;
     (0000001686601081020,10A)
     (0000001686601081020,08D)
     (0000001686601081020,08D)
     (0000001686601081020,08D)
     (0000001686601081020,09D)
     (0000001686601081020,09D)
     (0000001686601081020,08D)
     (0000001686601081020,08D)
     (0000001686601081020,08D)
     (0000001686676950125,0A1)
     (0000001686676950125,0A1)
     (0000001686676950125,0A2)
```

Column $0 is account_id, column $1 is cell_id.

For each account_id I need to find most frequant cell id.

First steps, that I tried to do were:

```
 grpd = group DATA_INPUT by ($0, $1);
 cells_count  = foreach grpd GENERATE group, COUNT(DATA_INPUT.$1) AS count;
 all_cells_counts = GROUP cells_count BY group.$0;
    top_cell = FOREACH all_cells_counts {
        A = ORDER cells_count BY count DESC;
        B = LIMIT A 1;
        GENERATE FLATTEN(B.group);
    }
```

The rezult I got:

```
     ((0000001686601081020,08D))
     ((0000001686676950125,0A1))
```

How can I get rid of brackets (), to have in the rezult

```
     (0000001686601081020,08D)
     (0000001686676950125,0A1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do FLATTEN of top_cell

```
final_result = FOREACH top_cell GENERATE FLATTEN($0);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! That is what I tried to do in many ways  
unsuccessfully:)